# simple update query taking very long to execute in MySQL (wait innodb)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a table with 54k rows, contains 10G of data

I am running this update query on it:

```
UPDATE my_table SET blog_object_version='19'
```

takes more than 1 **hour** to run, 
how can I improve performance?

**additional information:**

I am running on AMAZON rds, `db.m5.4xlarge` 
this is my instance:
[image]

this is what I see in the **aws performance insights**: 
`wait/io/file/innodb/innodb_data_file`

[image]

I do not have any other queries running on my db:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| Id | User     | Host                | db       | Command | Time | State    | Info                                         |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  3 | rdsadmin | localhost:65182     | NULL     | Sleep   |    0 |          | NULL                                         |
|  4 | rdsadmin | localhost           | NULL     | Sleep   |    1 |          | NULL                                         |
|  6 | admin    | 123.45.67.890:6170  | my_table | Query   | 3901 | updating | UPDATE my_table SET blog_object_version='19' |
| 12 | admin    | 123.45.67.890:6360  | NULL     | Sleep   | 2981 |          | NULL                                         |
| 18 | admin    | 123.45.67.890:7001  | NULL     | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist                             |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

and this is my table:

```
mysql> show create table my_table\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: my_table
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `associate_object_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `blog_object` longtext,
  `blog_object_version` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_user_id_version_id` (`id`,`user_id`,`version_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_id_associate_object_id` (`user_id`,`associate_object_id`),
  KEY `user_id_associate_object_id_version_id` (`user_id`,`associate_object_id`,`version_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54563151 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

these are my indexes:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM my_table;
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                               | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| my_table |          0 | PRIMARY                                |            1 | index               | A         |       43915 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          0 | id_user_id_version_id                  |            1 | id                  | A         |        3659 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          0 | id_user_id_version_id                  |            2 | user_id             | A         |        8783 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          0 | id_user_id_version_id                  |            3 | version_id          | A         |       43915 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          1 | user_id_associate_object_id            |            1 | user_id             | A         |         378 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          1 | user_id_associate_object_id            |            2 | associate_object_id | A         |        4391 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          1 | user_id_associate_object_id_version_id |            1 | user_id             | A         |         385 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          1 | user_id_associate_object_id_version_id |            2 | associate_object_id | A         |        6273 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_table |          1 | user_id_associate_object_id_version_id |            3 | version_id          | A         |       43915 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Is there an update trigger on this table that is performing extra writes? You have 54,000 records but the auto-increment ID is at 54.5-million. This suggests there may be a lot more being written than just the `blog_object_version` value 

Comment: dont see any triggers: `mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS;` -> 
`Empty set (0.15 sec)`

Comment: the auto increment is on 54 million - since the index files is auto incremented to each new added row, but rows might be deleted

Comment: I remember having an issue similar to this a long time ago with an update. To resolve the issue I needed *something* in the `WHERE` clause, no matter how silly. I went with using just the primary index: `WHERE id >= 0`. This took an update query from 30 seconds to 0.something seconds 

Comment: @matigo I tried this, didnt help...

Comment: When was the last time there was any maintenance on the indexes? An hour for 54K records on a `db.m5.4xlarge` is excessive …

Comment: 10GB in 54K rows --> 200KB per row?  Some big `TEXT` or `BLOB`?

Comment: @RickJames yes , `blog_object` -> longtext

Comment: If you edit the table very often, separate the longtext to an own table and use only an index in this table. My guess is, that because loggtest is of undefined length, on Update everything has to be reformatted in the database file,

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff - Yes and no.  InnoDB already puts "long" columns in "off-record" storage, leaving behind a pointer to it "on-record".  So, in most situation where you don't need the long column, there is no overhead for having it in the same "table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic issue, with a very basic solution:

```
INDEX(blog_object_version)
```

Why?  Without this index, the `UPDATE` must read *every* one of the 54K (or 54M?) rows to check for `'19'`.

With that index, only the relevant rows need to be read.

Tips:

Many of the `VARCHAR` columns sound like they should be `INT` (or something smaller, like `SMALLINT`)?  (Changing the types is not likely to speed up the query.)

Toss `user_id_associate_object_id`; the index `user_id_associate_object_id_version_id` handles the same things.

**Update all rows**

Updating up to 1K rows is reasonable.  Updating less than 20% of the table will *probably* use the index if it is suitable.

But...  If you need to update all of 54K rows, there are a couple of issues.

It will take a long time and probably a lot of disk space because both the old and new copies are held on to until the Update is finished.  (This is so that it can commit or rollback the entire Update atomically.)

Generally, it is "poor design" to ever need to update a column in all rows of an entire table.  Sometimes, it may be possible put the column in another table in a single row.  Then it is a one-row query to update `blog_object_version`.  But it means doing a `JOIN` when you need it in a `SELECT`.  (This may not be a problem.)  And if you aren't changing all the rows, then it is messier.

So,...  If you decide to update "a lot of" (or all of) a big table, I recommend doing it in chunks of 100-1000 rows each.  More details: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

**Change Buffer**

Another issue (less important) is that when updating an a non-unique indexed column, the index needs updating.  That requires modifications to the BTree that represents the `INDEX`.  For non-unique indexes, this is done in the background, mostly after the query is commited.

There is no risk of having an incorrect index before it finishes updating the BTree.  This is because of the "Change buffer".  That construct keeps pending index updates for later persisting to disk.

Comment: what if *all* my rows need to be updated ? will the index help?

Comment: I added advice on such.

Comment: @dina - I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

With this statement:

```
UPDATE my_table SET blog_object_version='19'
```

All records needs to be fetched, checked and updated. Because there is not WHERE clause.

If only some records needs to be updated (because the other ones already have `blog_object_version='19'`  then you might see a (small)  improvement if you do:

```
UPDATE my_table SET blog_object_version='19' WHERE blog_object_version != '19'
```

Because with his statement only the records that need a change are being updated, but still all records needs to be fetched.

If not all records have a `blog_object_version` whic is unequal to '19', then adding an index on this field might improve things, because then only thos records needs to be fetched with a `blob_object_version` unequal to '19'.

If all records need to have the update, then this will not improve anything ...

Comment: no, I need o update **all** 50k rows i table, I don't think it should take more than 1 hour- as is happening